# set numerical format of colorbar in python matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, colorbar

I am trying to set the scale of the numbers of a colorbar in matplotlib. (i.e. multiply all the values by 0.001), so I can use the label to indicate the scale (i.e. magnetic field in gaus*10^3) of the values. So far, I figured out, that I can set the rotation of the ticklabels via the

```
cbar1.ax.set_xticklabels(cbar1.ax.get_xticklabels(), size = 10, rotation=90)
```

comand. What I want to do now (it is not working, because the `get_xticklabels()` funktion doesn´t return a list or some integer values):

```
cbar1.ax.set_xticklabels((cbar1.ax.get_xticklabels()/1000), size = 10, rotation=90)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think most people do what you're trying to do by scaling the data that they input to their `ax.plot` function. For example, if you were doing a scatter plot you would do:

```
ax.scatter(x_data, y_data, c=gaus_data / 1000)
```